# 'document.getElementById' only works on index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getelementbyid

Ultimate goal is to cycle through photos on a blog page. Seems like 'document.getElementById().src' would be a good approach.

**Problem:** To make sure the javascript code is successfully linking to the blog page, I tried testing with this in my script.js file:

```
document.getElementById('testID').innerHTML = "Running test";
```

and this in my .html file:

```
<div id="testID"></div>
```

But, the text "Running Test" does not show up on the blog page. However, when running this same exact test in my index.html page, it *does* work. Both .html files load the same script file along with jQuery. I don't understand why it works in one html file and not the other.

**NEW FINDING:** 
This line of code now works on the blog page when I remove it from inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

Why would that be?

Comment: you can only get elements of rendered objects in the DOM. so if your other pages are not loaded... you can't use document.getElement... or any other plugin

Comment: Yes, I originally wrote "<div>" without realizing that stackoverflow would view that as actual HTML and not display it as text. I edited it by removed the brackets and just italicizing it.

Comment: Same answer @LiranBo said no matter what you did differently.

Comment: Thanks @LiranBo, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Perhaps I need a JS file in the same directory as the html file I'm trying to access?

Comment: @Matte3o Yes, StackOverflow parses HTML. You can avoid it by formatting as inline code, using `\``

Comment: document doesn't know or care about what file the html comes from ... it only knows about what exists, Not entirely clear what your issue is

Comment: In fact, part of the explanation is right in the code "document", as in the current HTML document.

Comment: @Oriol thanks for the edits and suggestion. I'll probably just go with inline code, although I'd like to keep my JS separate.

Comment: @Rob that makes sense. How could I get the current document to be a different .html file than the index.html file?  Meaning, how does it determine what the "current" html document is?

Comment: @Matte3o Start all over and explain what it is you want to accomplish at a higher level

Comment: maybe have you considered making another script file and just import that  script file inside the html page that you want to get things from, then in the script file do your calls to the relevant dom elements

Comment: The current .html file is the one that the URL in the browser requested and the Javascript code running in that page is the code in that page.  You can load a different page into the browser with `window.location = "http://somedomain.com/somepage.html";`, but then the current Javascript is no longer running as it will then start up the Javascript in the new page and shut down the old page.

Comment: or you can use ajax to load html from other files into the current document

Comment: @charlietfl - Sorry, I'm trying hard to be clear. I have a website with multiple HTML pages. I want to access divs in all the HTML pages (not just index.html) using getElementById.  I'm trying to change photos in my blog using javascript.

Comment: if you mean permanently you can't do that with simple javasript. Even if you change it in index and reload the page any changes you made are lost. There is no persistence between page loads

Comment: @Torean I've tried that, doesn't seem to be working. I created another script file, import it in the html page I'm trying to access elements from, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Matte3o you need a more dynamic server language approach than static html and simple dom manipulation javascript to do what you want

Comment: @charlietfl - No, I don't mean permanently. I want the images to change every couple seconds. I'm trying to do the same thing I do in the index.html file just on another page.

Comment: @charlietfl - Ok. I'll have to learn up on that, thank you. However, I still don't understand why I can do commands like "document.getelementbyid.innerHTML" in my index.html, but not in the other pages even though they're loaded.

Comment: If you just described what you were actually trying to accomplish from the very beginning and put that into your question, then you would have gotten an answer in a matter of minutes.  This site works a lot better when you describe the actual problem, not only describe your attempted (and sometimes misdirected) solution.  That way, we can offer you the best possible solution to your real problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the suggestion. I was afraid of not being specific enough since many questions get downvoted for that.

Comment: You can show the code you tried for the problem and where you got stuck, but please start by describing the overall problem first.  Then, if you're going down the wrong path, we can still help you without a zillion comments to clarify.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Ok understood. Should I reword the problem now? or just leave it alone?

Comment: You can either delete your question or use the "edit" link to fix it so it is 100% clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript in the current page can only access HTML elements that are in pages that are currently loaded into the browser.

More specifically, `document.getElementById()` ONLY searches the current web page's document for matching elements.  It does not search any other pages and certainly does not search other files on your server that are not loaded into the browser.  "current web page" means the HTML loaded from the current URL in the browser bar.

When a web page is no longer visible in the browser window (e.g it's been replaced by some other page), it is gone and no longer reachable by any Javascript.  In some specific cases, you can access document loaded into other tabs or other frames (subject to same-origin security rules and requires a different method of access).

In addition, no changes to a web page are persistent in the browser.  As soon as a web page is no longer loaded into an active browser window, it is gone and reloading it again will load the original, unmodified version of that document.

If you want the same code from one page to run in another page, then you must include that same code in the other page.  You can want, you can share a reference to the code by putting the code into its own page and then using a `<script src="xxx.js">` tag in each page to cause the same code to get loaded into each page.

Comment: @Matte3o - Added several more items to my answer as you continue to disclose what the real problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. Thanks for the thorough answer! I think my question was poorly worded and definitely misunderstood. I'm not trying to access pages that are not loaded. I want to access the page that *is* loaded.

Comment: @Matte3o - When the browser loads a page, it runs the Javascript in THAT page automatically.  Any script you want running in that page has to be in the source of that page.  I still have no idea what your question actually is.

Comment: I attempted to reword. I think I just have some strange bug that I assumed had to do with the location of the HTML file, but it's actually something else.

Comment: @Matte3o - probably you were running your code too soon before the elements of the page had been run.  `4

Comment: @Matte3o - probably you were running your code too soon before the elements from the page were loaded, thus it could not find the elements when you ran the script.  Putting your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {...})` ensures that jQuery waits to run your script until the page is loaded.  You can also just make sure your script tags are placed right before `</body>` to ensure everything else is loaded before the script runs.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, try using `.load()`

`$("#container").load("/blog/blog_1.html #testID")`